# Integrate traditional C# .NET Application with Parse

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

Is it possible to integrate the traditional C#/.NET Applications with Parse data backend? I used to develop C# application with .net about a few years ago and everything seems to have changed. On Parse website they only give me the option for Windows 8 SDK, but I am not sure if this type of application will run on all windows versions (at least from WinXP) just like the old C# applications i used to make.

Comment: yes. they have a .NET SDK; and you can always just make REST Calls from your server using the API keys they provide.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do some more research in their website.

https://www.parse.com/products/dotnet

Here's the sample code:

```
// Create a new Parse object
var post = new ParseObject("Post");
post["title"] = "Hello World";

// Save it to Parse
await post.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: @Lukesoft Glad to help.